# delete last row in TableView and show a "no results" label in new cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem with my UITableView where deleting the last row in the section terminates the app with an NSInternalInconsistencyException:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

My UITableView is populated with MPMediaItems from an MPMediaItemCollection (self.detailCollection). When the last one gets deleted I want to show a "No results found" label in a blank cell.

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...

if ([[self.detailCollection items] count] == 0) {
    [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"No results found";
    //return cell;
} else {

 MPMediaItem *song = (MPMediaItem *)[[self.detailCollection items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
 if (song) {

 cell.textLabel.text = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
     MPMediaItemArtwork *art = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
     cell.imageView.image = [art imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(64, 64)];

 }
 }
   return cell;
 }
```

Here is my code for deleting the rows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
PlaylistData *pData = [PlaylistData getInstance];
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[self.eventDictionary valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", pData.selectedEvent]] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.eventDictionary setValue:tempArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", pData.selectedEvent]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.eventDictionary forKey:@"Playlist Items"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    if ([tempArray count] == 0) {
        [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<[tempArray count]; i++) {

        NSString *pID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tempArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        unsigned long long ullvalue = strtoull([pID UTF8String], NULL, 0);
        NSNumber *UniqueID = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:ullvalue];
        MPMediaQuery *cellQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
        [cellQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:UniqueID forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID]];

        for (MPMediaItem *item in [cellQuery items]) {
            [newArray addObject:item];
        }
        [cellQuery release];

    }
    if (![newArray count] == 0) {

    self.detailCollection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:newArray];
    [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[self.detailCollection count]];
    } else {
        [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1];

        [tableView reloadData];
    }
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableView endUpdates];

}
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}   
}
```

And here is my numberOfRowsInSection:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.


if ([[self.detailCollection items] count] == 0 || [self.detailCollection items] == nil || [self.detailCollection items] == NULL) {

return 1;
}

return [[self.detailCollection items] count];
}
```

**My question is: Why isn't it creating the "No results found" cell when self.detailCollection is == 0?**

Comment: I don't think that [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1] is doing what you think it's doing. You're not setting anything there. The argument that method takes is not the number of rows but the section index. You only define the number of rows returned for the table view in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: Thanks, I definitely thought I was setting the number of rows there. Now having commented that out I am still getting the same internal consistency error. It seems that it is setting the number of rows correctly (1) after the deletion, but it is expecting there to be zero rows. I am trying to make it expect 1 row, containing the cell with the "No results found" text.

Comment: Also, this line is redundant `if ([[self.detailCollection items] count] == 0 || [self.detailCollection items] == nil || [self.detailCollection items] == NULL)`. `self.detailCollection.items.count == 0` will suffice because count will be 0 off items is null

Comment: what is the `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1];` line for? you just cannot call this method as is...

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something to the effect of:

```
 [tableView beginUpdates];       

 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

 if ([newArray count] == 0) {

       [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
 }

 [tableView endUpdates];
```

However, a simpler solution would be to just add a label to your table view. Unless there is some specific reason that you need an actual UITableViewCell to display "No results found".

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0);
label.frame = frame;
label.text = @"No results found";
[self.tableView addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I would recommend is to use a table footer view rather than a new cell. Basically, add a footer to your table that is only visible when the cell count is 0.

You can override the method
`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`
 
to get a footer.

When deleting and adding objects, check the new count and then adjust the visibility of the footer from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling numberOfRowsInSection in a couple of places. You should never be calling it, it's a call back hook that you implement and the system calls.

The cleanest solution to do this would be to set `self.tableView.tableFooterView` when rows = 0

```
@interface UITableView : UIScrollView <NSCoding> {

...

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *tableFooterView; 
// accessory view below content. default is nil. not to be confused with section footer
```